# Restore a SQL .bak file using a VB script?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am exploring methods to enable users to restore a database from within the project.

I have a project which I want to publish together with the database, so that users with no experience can use the program I have developed.

The code is written in VB script and I am able to publish the VB code, but am finding it difficult to include the database in the ClickOnce method.

I have been thinking that I could possibly copy the .bak file to the client's PC and then run a VB script that restores the database to the SQLserver that is installed in the ClickOnce install.

Has anyone ever done this?

I did find on the web something that looked promising, but it has been written for .NET framework 2.0 or 3.0 and I found that when I added `System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.0` I got the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Could not install package 'System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v2.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

The website where I got the code: http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1433&lngWId=10

Please can anyone help?

Comment: VBScript or vb.net? Either way, you need to issue a [RESTORE DATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) command. Whether it's ado (VBScript), ADO.NET (VB.NET) or some other mechanism depends on your technology stack

Comment: You might think I'm a bit thick, but how do you know what type it is?

Comment: You might think I'm a bit thick, but how do you know what type it is? I have written the code using Visual Studio 2017 Professional,  Windows form application and am using SQLExpress database.  I know how to write SQL statement to restore and can do that from SSMS, but that is not the question! Can you write code within the Visual basic code that will restore the database to the empty SQL database Server?

Answer (score 0):

VBScript, which would get run via wscript.exe is decades old technology

VB.NET, which would get compiled into a custom .exe or .dll, is 2005+ (not included in this is .net core which is the past few years but I've not touched it)

```
dim connectionString as string = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
dim connection as New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
Dim query As String = "RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 FROM AdventureWorksBackups;"

Try
    cmd.CommandText = query
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("something bad happened")

End Try
```

Reference bits

ExecuteNonQuery https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8

Restore database https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

and if you're not using OLEDB, or need a different provider, then futz with connection string as needed but that's the general approach